# how can I find out why a custom widget isn't showing up in the Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, custom-controls, qt-designer

I created a custom widget by following the instructions provided in Qt Creator's help. I followed everything exactly as they said there. My widget isn't showing up with the other widgets. I even tried their WorldTimeClock example. That doesn't show in the Qt Designer either.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools -> Form Editor -> About Qt Designer plugins, you will find a list of loaded qt plugins, and you will see an error message next to the ones that failed to load. I think that's the best you can get.

Comment: This is the first step to make sure it loads. If it doesn't even get loaded, then you don't have to worry about the code itself. Most often you compiled in Debug instead of Release when it doesn't load.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this situation.  From what I could find, the distributed version of Qt Creator was compiled with msvc, not mingw.  Try opening Qt Designer.  Do you see your (and the built-in) custom widgets?  If so, follow the instructions [here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/34938/compile-qtcreator-with-mingw.html#post111534) to build Qt Creator with mingw.  When I did this, my custom widgets appeared in the new build.